# VS2022 cannot start diagnostic session

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Launching a CPU Usage performance profiler session in VS 2022 hangs indefinitely on:

```
"Starting diagnostics session"
```

After cancelling there is this error message in the Diagnostic hub output window:

```
'[ProjectName]' failed to launch
'Invalid operation detected by 'StandardClientTransportConnection.SendCustomMessageAsync'.'
```

The project compiles and runs fine. I have tried resetting my all Environment Options to a default set (I tried both Web Development and Web Development(Code only)). I've updated and repaired the installation of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/592556/diagnostics-session-failed-to-start) I checked that Visual Studio Standard Collector Service 150 is enabled and ran it manually (It was not running).

Restarting Visual Studio and running profiler session was then successful.